# Getting the Exception error while converting Docx file to XML using Apache POi

Tags: exception, apache-poi

Getting the following Exception Error

java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x4353414E2023233C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:140)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:104)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.(POIFSFileSystem.java:138)
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocumentCore.verifyAndBuildPOIFS(HWPFDocumentCore.java:107)
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.(HWPFDocument.java:179)
    at Word2XML.main(Word2XML.java:196)

Comment: I cant post it right now because i am new to it i can post it after 7 hr . I can mail you if you want.

Comment: Are you really trying to read a .docx file with the code that handles .doc files? Or is your question wrong? Only if you are trying to read a .docx file with HWPF, then you need to switch to XWPF which is the right POI module!

Comment: Sorry by mistake docx its doc file http://www.massapi.com/source/poi-3.7/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hwpf/Word2Forrest.java.html  Here you will find the code